What is the right way of disposing TextEditingController while using Provider package
I'm using provider for state management and I wanted to know what's the right of way disposing a text editing controller so that there will be no memory leaks.
FormProvider.dart
class FormProvider with ChangeNotifier{
    final emailController = TextEditingController();

    @override
    void dispose() {
    emailController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
    }
}

so when I leave the page where the TextFormField is located, the input/text I entered persists, isn't disposing the controller supposed to clear the TextFormField?

that depends on where and how do you use FormProvider in your code;
In FormProvider, you correctly dispose of the emailController in the dispose method. But still, you need to ensure that the FormProvider itself has a lifecycle that corresponds to the widget that owns it (typically a StatefulWidget)
take a look at this:
lets say you are using FormProvider in MyView, it should be something like this:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class MyView extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyView({super.key});

  @override
  MyViewState createState() => MyViewState();
}

class MyViewState extends State<MyView> {
  late FormProvider _formProvider; // Declare the FormProvider instance

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _formProvider = FormProvider(); // Initialize the FormProvider instance
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _formProvider.dispose(); // Dispose of the FormProvider instance
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => _formProvider, // Provide the FormProvider instance
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Form Page'),
        ),
        body: Consumer<FormProvider>(
          builder: (context, formProvider, _) => Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                TextField(
                  controller: formProvider.emailController,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Email'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FormProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  final TextEditingController emailController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    emailController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}

EDIT:
however in your case (initializing and disposing of a TextEditingController() in a separate ChangeNotifier) is not something usual, if this is your only use case of it, I suggest using flutter_hooks package which has a property called useTextEditingController() that will do all the hard works for you, and there is no need for your to initialize and dispose TextEditingController() anymore,
so import flutter_hooks package in your project, change your widget to a HookConsumerWidget and there define the useTextEditingController() without any extra step.
here take a look at this:
//chage your widget to a HookConsumerWidget
class MainScreen extends HookConsumerWidget {
  const MainScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    //use useTextEditingController it does all the hard works for you
    final emailController = useTextEditingController();

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Welcome'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Container(
              width: MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).width * 0.8,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(44),
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              child: TextField(
                controller: emailController,
                },

              //... rest of your code

I suggest you read the flutter_hooks documentation; it has so many good examples and explanations on how to effectively manage widget state and lifecycle in Flutter applications using hooks. It simplifies complex stateful logic, reduces boilerplate code, and improves code readability by encapsulating logic directly within functional components.

Okay but what's the point of using provider if I end up using Stateful widget?

@Abel let me update the answer, it would be more convinient

@Abel I edited the answer take a look at it and let me know if there is something else.
